# Vb.Net scoping question - private fields

Tags: vb.net

I have been looking at a class that has a method that accepts a parameter that is of the same type of the class containing the method.

```
Public Class test
   private _avalue as integer
   Public Sub CopyFrom(ByVal from as test)
     _avalue = from._avalue
   End Sub
End Class
```

When used in code

```
a.CopyFrom(b)
```

It appears that instance "a" has visibility to the private members of the passed in instance "b" and the line

```
_avalue = from._avalue
```

runs without error copying the private field from one object instance to the other.

Does anyone know if this is by design.  I was under the impression that a private field was only accessible by the instance of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `private` scope is related to the *type* not the *instance*. So yes, this is by design.

The class `test` has knowledge about the private parts of itself, so it can use those parts also on other instances of the same type.

Answer (score 2):

You are writing something similar to to a copy constructor. 
Since the copying method/function is being written inside of the same class, it will have access to private variables of any instance of its own class.